# PHP Excel error - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am loading a very small excel file with a size of 10 KB (40 rows & 18 columns) using PHPExcel but it always give me memory size error. I know that the file size is very small hence there is something wrong in the code but unable to figure out.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$this->load->library('PHPExcel');
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

$data = excelToArray($upload_filename);
```

I used a function to load and convert the file content into an array:

```
function excelToArray($filePath, $header=true){
        //Create excel reader after determining the file type
        $inputFileName = $filePath;
        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        /** Set read type to read cell data onl **/
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        //Get worksheet and built array with first row as header
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        //excel with first row header, use header as key
        if($header){
            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestDataRow();
            $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
            $headingsArray = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',null, true, true, true);
            $headingsArray = $headingsArray[1];
            $r = -1;
            $namedDataArray = array();
            for ($row = 3; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $dataRow = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,null, true, true, true);
                if ((isset($dataRow[$row]['A'])) && ($dataRow[$row]['A'] > '')) {
                    ++$r;
                    foreach($headingsArray as $columnKey => $columnHeading) {
                        $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = $dataRow[$row][$columnKey];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //excel sheet with no header
            $namedDataArray = $objWorksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);
        }
        return $namedDataArray;
}
```

I have tried to narrowed it down to following line where the script fails:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Another important point, This code works fine on localhost but giving error on godaddy server.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can edit the memory_limit line in your php.ini (if you have access to that file) to increase memory to 64M:

memory_limit = 64M;

2) If you can't get to the php.ini file, add this line at the top of your .htaccess file:

php_value memory_limit 64M

If that doesn't work or throws a "500 Internal Server Error", delete the line from .htaccess.